# Restricting update on API endpoint for unauthorized users

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have built an API only app using API resource and Passport for authentication. The app does the following

1. Allow everyone list all books and view a particular book
2. Allow only logged in users add, update and delete books belonging to them

Using postman, the app works as intended except for update and delete operations. If a user tries to update a book not belonging to them, I want an error response returned. Unfortunately I get a 200 Ok status code instead of my custom message and a 403 status code. It's the same thing with the delete too.

This is my BookController update and delete methods

```
public function update(Request $request, Book $book)
{
    // Update book if the logged in user_id is the same as the book user_id
    if ($request->user()->id === $book->user_id) {
        $book->update($request->only(['title', 'author']));

        return new BookResource($book);
    } else {
        response()->json(['error' => 'You do not have the permission for this operation'], 403);
    }
}

public function destroy(Request $request, Book $book)
{
    // Delete book only if user_id matches book's user_id
    if ($request->user()->id === $book->user_id) {
        $book->delete();

        return response()->json(null, 204);
    } else {
        response()->json(['error' => 'You do not have the permission for this operation'], 403);
    }
}
```

NOTE: When testing in postman, I simply add the bearer token in the headers authorization field. Works when user owns the book but get 200 instead of 403 status code when the book is not owned by logged in user.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Found the error, I was not returning the error response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to return your response in the `else` statement - you can simplify it like so:

```php
public function update(Request $request, Book $book)
{
    // Update book if the logged in user_id is the same as the book user_id
    if ($request->user()->id === $book->user_id) {
        $book->update($request->only(['title', 'author']));

        return new BookResource($book);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'error' => 'You do not have the permission for this operation'
    ], 403);
}

public function destroy(Request $request, Book $book)
{
    // Delete book only if user_id matches book's user_id
    if ($request->user()->id === $book->user_id) {
        $book->delete();

        return response()->json(null, 204);
    }

    return response()->json(['error' => 'You do not have the permission for this operation'], 403);
}
```

I would also suggest perhaps looking into policies - and apply them as middleware to the routes https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#writing-policies

Comment: I figured. Thanks chief